# Power Query - running total that resets when values change

Tags: powerquery

I have been searching for a week now and cannot find a resolution to my problem.  I have a table which lists the "event" and individual is in during a certain week.  I want to add a column  - via PowerQuery - that will count the number of weeks a person has been in that event and then resets if the event changes in the following week.  For example...

| Pers1 | Date | Event | Weeks in Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pers1 | 12/22/2022 | Consideration | 1 |
| Pers1 | 12/26/2022 | Consideration | 2 |
| Pers1 | 1/05/2022 | Interview | 1 |
| Pers1 | 1/12/2022 | Consideration | 1 |
| Pers1 | 1/19/2022 | Consideration | 2 |
| Pers1 | 1/26/2022 | Awaiting Hire | 1 |
| Pers2 | 1/19/2022 | Awaiting Hire | 1 |
| Pers2 | 1/26/2022 | Awaiting Hire | 2 |

Note how the count resets back to starting at 1 when Pers1 has their second stint of Consideration during weeks 1/12 and 1/19.  Additionally, I need the solution to be smart enough to distinguish between two different individuals and uniquely count their time in an event.

This community has always come through for me.  Please help!

EDIT 1:  I incorporated the code provided by Ron and am receiving the following error: Expression.Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=List

PQ Advanced Editor Code is below:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Location"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Pers1", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}}),

//add an offset column for Pers and Event to do easy comparison with previous row
    offsetPersonEvent=Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") 
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Pers1]) & {null}}
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Event]) & {null}},
            type table[Pers=text, Date=date,Event=text,offsetPers=text, offsetEvent=text] 
    ),

//create "grouper" column by checking where both Pers and Event change
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(offsetPersonEvent, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "groups", 
        each if [Pers]=[offsetPers] and [Event]=[offsetEvent] then null else [Index]),

//remove unneeded columns, fillUp the grouper, and group by "grouper"
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"offsetPers", "offsetEvent", "Index"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"groups"}),

//Add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", {"groups"}, {
        {"addedIndex", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Weeks in Event",1,1,Int64.Type)
        , type table}}),

//Remove unneccessary columns
//  Expand the grouped tables
//  reset the data types
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"groups"}),
    #"Expanded addedIndex" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "addedIndex", {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}, {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded addedIndex",{{"Pers", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}, {"Weeks in Event", Int64.Type}})
    
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: Are we supposed to convert dates to weeks somehow or just assume different dates are different weeks

Comment: No need to convert dates.  My system checks each Wednesday and records the event, so each date is a different week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is sorted by Person and then by Date, as you show, you can use the following M-Code.

*(If your data is not so sorted, then you could merely add steps initially to sort it appropriately, and then continue with the code shown)*

*Please read the code comments and examine the Applied steps to understand the algorithm*

Open the Advanced Editor and paste in the code below

```
let

//change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Pers1", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}}),

//add an offset column for Pers and Event to do easy comparison with previous row
    offsetPersonEvent=Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") 
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Pers1]) & {null}}
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Event]) & {null}},
            type table[Pers=text, Date=date,Event=text,offsetPers=text, offsetEvent=text] 
    ),

//create "grouper" column by checking where both Pers and Event change
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(offsetPersonEvent, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "groups", 
        each if [Pers]=[offsetPers] and [Event]=[offsetEvent] then null else [Index]),

//remove unneeded columns, fillUp the grouper, and group by "grouper"
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"offsetPers", "offsetEvent", "Index"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"groups"}),

//Add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", {"groups"}, {
        {"addedIndex", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Weeks in Event",1,1,Int64.Type)
        , type table}}),

//Remove unneccessary columns
//  Expand the grouped tables
//  reset the data types
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"groups"}),
    #"Expanded addedIndex" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "addedIndex", {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}, {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded addedIndex",{{"Pers", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}, {"Weeks in Event", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Ron, can't thank you enough for helping.  I've incorporated your code, but am receiving the following error: Expression. Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
    Pattern=
    Arguments=List

Comment: I've added the new code from the Advanced Editor into the original question.

Comment: Ron, I've methodically added each step of your code to my query and the error presents after adding this section: //Add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", {"groups"}, {
        {"addedIndex", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Weeks in Event",1,1,Int64.Type)
        , type table}}),

Comment: @J.S. That is odd. Clearly it works here or I would not have been able to post the screenshots.  Just to double check, I copy pasted your table from your question (deleting the last column), then copy/pasted my code as posted, and it worked fine with **Int64.Type**.  I wonder if there is a PQ version issue.  And according to the MS documentation, `Table.AddIndexColumn` can have 2 to **5** arguments, with the fifth argument being the column type.  Oh well, it is an optional argument.  Just wonder why it works (or doesn't work) that way on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Ron's code worked with one minor tweak.  For me, the following section of code was causing an error

```
//Add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", {"groups"}, {
        {"addedIndex", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Weeks in Event",1,1,Int64.Type)
        , type table}}),
```

I removed the Int64.Type parameter from the Table.AddIndexColumn and everything functioned.  I've included the updated code snip-it below:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Location"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Pers1", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}}),

    //add an offset column for Pers and Event to do easy comparison with previous row
    offsetPersonEvent=Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") 
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Pers1]) & {null}}
            & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Event]) & {null}},
            type table[Pers=text, Date=date,Event=text,offsetPers=text, offsetEvent=text] 
    ),

    //create "grouper" column by checking where both Pers and Event change
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(offsetPersonEvent, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "groups", 
        each if [Pers]=[offsetPers] and [Event]=[offsetEvent] then null else [Index]),

    //remove unneeded columns, fillUp the grouper, and group by "grouper"
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"offsetPers", "offsetEvent", "Index"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"groups"}),

    //Add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", "groups", {
        {"addedIndex", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Weeks in Event",1,1)
        , type table}}),

    //Remove unneccessary columns
    //  Expand the grouped tables
    //  reset the data types
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"groups"}),
    #"Expanded addedIndex" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "addedIndex", {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}, {"Pers", "Date", "Event", "Weeks in Event"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded addedIndex",{{"Pers", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}, {"Weeks in Event", Int64.Type}})

in
    #"Changed Type1"
```